# R function for post hoc pairwise comparisons of MANOVA

Tags: r, posthoc, manova

Anyone know about an R function for **post hoc pairwise comparisons** after a **MANOVA** test, that is, check for groups differences for several variables (I only know functions to do ANOVA post hoc comparisons such as pairwise.t.test() or TukeyHSD(), but not after MANOVA with several variables)? Thanks!